# How can I find a good way to understand words like acronyms/slang?

Tags: discussion, non-english-speakers

This post is prompted by [a question I revised](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15547581/can-you-write-c-wrappers-in-c-sharp-instead-of-using-c-cli).

In the question body the OP used the word `'ol`. I had to search for a long time to figure out what that meant, and found that it is an acronym of `old`.

Since it contains a symbol, it is not as easy to search as a keyword on Google. And even when I get a result, I would need to filter for the possibility according to the frequency it appears in the result.

Moving on to the answers, someone used `w/o`. And my brain reports a compiling error:

- Brain Error KK0411

  > The semantic meaning for string 'w/o' cannot be inferred from the usage. 
  >   Try specifying the semantic meaning explicitly.

What does that mean? Does `w/o` stand for *write out*? Or *write only*? `write off` perhaps? Or any possible word which is one of [WO on wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WO)?

I've also read this question on Meta: [Can people PLEASE spell out their slang acronyms](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94978/can-people-please-spell-out-their-slang-acronyms)

So my question is, how can I find a good and easy way to understand the slang people use? Especially those which contain a symbol character?

Further, could Stack Exchange do this favor for people who are not native English speakers?

Comment: Is there a question somewhere in this rant? Stack Exchange is not a single person, you know? It is a community of people from **around the world**.

Comment: w/o = without, but yeah, annoying stuff.

Comment: There is a small glossary here:  http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/3670/i-saw-something-in-chat-i-dont-understand

Comment: I guess my point with the first comment is - the content is community created and edited. Stack Exchange can't control what and how people write.

Comment: w/o?  I haven't looked at your question yet, but I'm guessing that it means **without**.  Am I right?

Comment: @SamIam You're not right, you're sam.

Comment: I find (perhaps surprisingly), that in most of the edits I make, the use of such non-standard/alternative spelling is very often a sign of non-native speakers. P.s. NEVER start your Meta posts with the message that you expect to be downvoted. We tend to do everything to meet a user's expectation. ;) But other than that it's completely unnecessary fluff.

Comment: @Oded: Just because of its a community of people from **around the world**.

Comment: Yes, but how can Stack Exchange monitor and manually edit over 7000 posts a day (on Stack Overflow alone)?

Comment: @Oded We should hire interns for some "detail-oriented curation of user-generated content in a fast-paced environment".

Comment: @AnnaLear I'm sure they would get to work with some great "characters"?

Comment: @AnnaLear If I could put Stack Exchange on my resume, I'd take that job.

Comment: @Shog9 isn't that a bit too much of a title change? I'd reject that as 'too radical' any day of the week.

Comment: I may have taken a few liberties when expanding some of the abbreviations.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII If the title serves the purpose to inform you about the content of a question....I'd take the new title over the old one. Even if the edit is radical.

Comment: ol' is an abbreviation of old, not an acronym. /pointlessblathering

Comment: Nitpick - BTW is not slang. It is an acronym of By The Way.

Comment: @Oded: Nitpick: BTW could be considered [slang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slang). (“Internet slang”, specifically.)

Comment: Thanks to everybody. I marked the hightest voted one.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

First of all, *w/o* isn't slang, it's an abbreviation. It appears in [Oxford](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/w/o?q=w%2Fo), [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/w/o), American Heritage, Collins and Random House Kernerman Webster ([source](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/w%2Fo)). All of those except Collins say it should only mean *without*.

That being said, I'm still in favor of spelling it out on Stack Overflow.

> So my question is, how can I find a good and easy way to understand the slang people use? Especially those which contain a symbol character?

Try [Merriam-Webster's Learner's Dictionary](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/).

I tried searching for [*w/o*](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/search/w/o), [*ol'*](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/search/ol') and even [*'ol*](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/search/'ol); it found matches without problems.

Answer (score 7):

If someone uses a slang term or abbreviation that you don't understand you should do the same thing as when anyone says anything that you don't understand.  **You should ask them what they meant**.  It's as simple as adding a comment saying, "I'm not familiar with the term 'ol'', what do you mean by that?" and you'll get your answer.

If a lot of people seem to have trouble digesting a post due to overuse of slang/abbreviations, or the use of particularly obscure slang/abbreviations you can consider editing the post to write them out, or asking the author to edit the post themselves to do the same.  In particular this makes more sense when the slang/abbreviation isn't specific to the topic(s) at hand.  A slang term for a programming tool that the question relates to is likely appropriate, for example.

SE sites aren't language documentation pages; they're interactive.  If you think a post isn't clear just say so (and try to explain, specifically, what needs fixing).

Comment: I'm not familiar with the term 'SE', what do you mean by that?

Comment: @Dennis I have no idea what it means, I'm just repeating random buzzwords that I hear other people saying in an attempt to sound smart.  Feel free to edit it in if you know it.

Comment: @Dennis SE is the plural of SO.

Comment: @Yannis How does stack overflows abbreviate to SE?

Comment: @Servy: That might be kind of humor of Yannis.

Comment: @KenKin The entire comment thread to this answer isn't serious at all.  Dennis knows what SE stands for, as do I, and as does Yannis.  He's mocking me (all in good fun).

Comment: @Servy In the beginning there was SO. Then we made 100 mini sites just like SO, and called them SE.

Answer (score 4):

The question you linked has far from a major problem. At least here in the United States, *ol'* as a word is used quite often, and in context it makes total sense.

My rule is this: When in doubt, read it out loud.

That's not to say that there isn't a problem as a whole, however, it has been discussed before: [What should we do with experienced users who constantly use slang and shorthand?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/146315/what-should-we-do-with-experienced-users-who-constantly-use-slang-and-shorthand), [Can people PLEASE spell out their slang acronyms](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94978/can-people-please-spell-out-their-slang-acronyms?lq=1), [Should leetspeak be edited out of posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129729/should-leetspeak-be-edited-out-of-posts), and many other times, and there's no need to be so abrasive about it.

When you come across it, fix it like you did, and *move on*.

Comment: I think the problem is the fact that this makes it very hard to search for things sometimes..

Comment: @Seth debatable. If you are using SO's search, then yes it can be hard, but Google most certainly has acronym support in their searches.

Comment: It's usually *ol'*, though. The apostrophe indicates the omitted *d*.

Comment: @Caleb I've seen it both ways, it usually depends on the source

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII Yes, but one is correct and one is not. (Many colloquial phrases are repeated incorrectly by people who don't stop to think about what they mean. Prime example: *I could care less.*) Looking at the original form of the question at hand, it was *'ol* there, and the fact that the incorrect version was used probably contributed to the OP not being able to find a definition.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII: Thank you!